# Using I2C in C++ on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, i2c, software-development, rtc

I have a Raspberry Pi model B with Raspbian and a [Busware SD0](http://busware.de/tiki-index.php?page=SD0) cape.
The SD0 has an RTC that can be read via the I2C bus. I want set the time and date of the Raspberry Pi because it is not always connected to the internet so the time can't be set via NTP.

Is it possible to use I2C without using "external" libraries like WiringPi (like you can use the UART via a Linux kernel module)?

Comment: Please be aware that I think the Linux kernel supports some I2C RTC chips.  I am not sure if the DS1338 is one of the supported ones though.

Comment: (Cheers @joan).  The DS1338 is mentioned as compatible in the source for the DS1307 driver.   This driver is in Raspbian. You could try `sudo modprobe rtc-ds1307`; then I guess check `hwclock`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel has [an API for SMBus/I2C](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol).  You just have to include a couple of headers:

```
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

There's no library that needs linking. I've used this to write C++ based interfaces to various I2C sensors, I'm sure it can be made to work with an RTC.  The API isn't the complicated part, it's figuring out how to use it in relation to a datasheet.

I did notice that sometimes that using a `read()` or `write()` on the file descriptor in a manner that should have duplicated an `i2c_smbus` function did not produce the same result.  I mention this because if one method does not seem to work, try the other.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use a third party library to access I2C.

Just search for Linux I2C to find code examples.

Here is a Pi example of mine to read an [ADXL345](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_code) accelerometer via I2C.  Note, this code defaults to bus 0.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `bus 0`. I wasted almost 2 days once for making a driver work. :( All I had to do was to change a `0` to `1`. :)

Answer (score 0):

An answer from 7 years later:

Currently (2023.4), you'd better to use a library `libi2c` to alleviate I2C development, instead of fully using `ioctl`s and `linux/i2c.h`. Actually it is a shallow API wrapper for the I2C/SMBus declaration in linux kernel.

Edit:

You even don't need any libraries, it is actually integrated inside the Linux I2C driver if your device conforms to the SMBus behavior. What you need is only:

- Open the i2c file device by `open("/dev/i2c-X", O_RDWR )`.
- Set the current using slave address by `fcntl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, YOUR_SLAVE_ADDRESS)`. The macro `I2C_SLAVE` is defined in `linux/i2c-dev.h`.
- Perform simple `read` and `write` on the file descriptor. Corresponding SMBus transaction is automatically performed by underlying Linux I2C driver.

These operations are enough for operating all functions of BH1750 ambient light sensor.